# Mongodb, Delete one object from an array of objects using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, object, mongoose

I am trying to remove one object from an array of my collection, which looks like this. It s a collection in Mongodb

[image]

Before deleting a specific object based on chartId, I need to check the userId and the name of the array. Then I need to delete the object.

I have written this code, but its not working.  someone will tell me what exactly I am missing in this code.

```
           delChartObj.updateOne(
    { 'userId': userId },
    { $pull: { "Color": { "chartId": req_chart_id } } },
    { safe: true, multi: true}, function (err, obj) {
        if (err) { res.send.err }

        res.status(200).send({ msg: "Deleted Sucessfully" });
    });
```

In my case, userId = ADAM, array = "Color" and chartID = time
I am using mongoose for performing action

delChartObj is an object of model

```
 const UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
userId: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
charts: { type: Object },


 });
```

Answer (score 0):

try this in pull

```
{ $pull: { "Chart.Color.$.chartId": req_chart_id } } },
```

Comment: Nothing happens, code executed but it hasn't deleted from collection

Comment: I have update the question basically you are not mention top level attribute which is chart

Answer (score 0):

You should do findOneAndUpdate, the syntax will be something like:

```
Model.findOneAndUpdate(
< condition>,
{ $pull: { "Color.$.chartId": req_chart_id } } }, // The actual Query
{ new: true }
)
```